# RMSD / Tm metric for comparing local molecular structure similarity?

Tags: protein-structure, structural-biology, 3d-structure, biopython

I would like to compare two molecular (protein) structures, but rather than comparing the total, global structures against themselves to yield an RMSD score (which would be straightforward with a structural alignment in PyMOL or similar), I instead am interested in a particular localised structural region in each protein.  Specifically, all atoms within a 20Å radius of a particular residue's alpha-carbon coordinates.

For example, I would have the local structure of L100 (in protein A) and L200 (from protein B), defined as the atoms that are within the radius threshold of those residues respectively.  To compare the "local structures" of L100 and L200, I know that they should be superimposed at the same site as they are the same residue (so I can "enforce" that the alpha-carbon coords of both residues should be in the same spot, i.e. the origin (0,0,0)).  Now, this becomes a "rotation optimisation" problem in order to get the minimal RMSD score.  I have so far found the [Kabsch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabsch_algorithm) as one way to achieve this, as there is no need for working out the "translation" of the two separate structures (again, we know that we should enforce the centre residues to be in the same position).

However, the Kabsch algorithm can only work on the *same number* of points in structure A and structure B; but I may be comparing pairs of structures with an arbitrary number of atoms.  Additionally, due to differing amino acid compositions in the local structure, a different number of each *element* may be present between the two structures.

I am not sure if there is a solved way of getting the "distance" score between two local structures in this way; and I also am struggling to understand how other structure scores such as a global RMSD (between two *different* proteins of different length) or Tm (from Tm-align) work with two sets of points with different sizes.  Would appreciate any help!

TLDR;
How to find RMSD score / optimal rotation between two sets of atom coordinates (like Kabsch algorithm), when the two sets have differing numbers of points?

Comment: Don't have time to look into it too much right now but have you looked at methods like this https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-7-40